# Add CATransition animation to UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, core-animation, transition

I want to add `CATransition` to `UIViewControllers` which i am displaying using `NSTimer`

```
-(void)playAction:(id)sender
{
[audioPlayer play];
[self performSelector:@selector(displayviewsAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:11.0];
}

- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{  
 First *firstController = [[First alloc] init];
 firstController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
 [self.view addSubview:firstController.view];
 [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
 [firstController release];   
 self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(Second) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];     
 }

-(void)Second 
{
Second *secondController = [[Second alloc] init];
secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[secondController release];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:27 target:self selector:@selector(Third) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

How i can add `CATransition` to these `UIViewControllers` when they change from first to second and so on.

Thanks in advance for all ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this -

```
-(void)Second {
    Second *secondController = [[Second alloc] init];
    secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
    [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
    [transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionReveal];
    [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];

    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionReveal];

    [self.view addSubview:secondController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
    [secondController release];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:27 target:self selector:@selector(Third) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

// you can define your own `CATransition` animation type in this.

Comment: can i have flip catransition.

Comment: there a couple of animation type are present, you can check this for more details - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html